# O que é Reason?

Tags: terminologia

Recentemente ouvi falar de [Reason](https://reasonml.github.io/), porém não sei do que se trata, alguns chamam de linguagem de programação, outros de uma sintaxe alimentada por OCaml, sei que é liderado pelo Facebook e que é muito bom para aplicações gráficas/jogos simples, além de usar JavaScript na sintaxe, por fim, do que se trata essa tecnologia? vale a pena aprender?

Comment: Já ouvi falar, mas não é uma linguagem. É uma sintaxe que usa a linguagem OCaml para alguma coisa relacionada a JavaScript. Mas nunca fui atrás de saber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reason](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/what-and-why.html) é uma linguagem que mistura Ocaml e JavaScript. Ela foi desenvolvida para facilitar a vida de programadores JavaScript (assim eles não precisam aprender Ocaml propriamente dito) e também para facilitar a geração de código por parte do compilador (Ocaml e JavaScript têm algumas diferenças significativas).

Existe um compilador chamado [BuckleScript](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/what-why) que compila de Ocaml/Reason para JavaScript.

---

Na página que eu linkei diz o seguinte (em tradução livre):

> Reason não é uma nova linguagem, é uma nova sintaxe e um conjunto de ferramentas

Mas em termos práticos pode-se dizer que é uma nova linguagem sim (que propositalmente possui muitas similaridades com Ocaml).